# Delphi Apple Push Notification not working on iOS while working on Android

Tags: ios, delphi, apple-push-notifications, firemonkey

I'm trying to include the `Apple Push Notifications` inside my `iOS` application following [this example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n_C5_GxQhk4).

After some debugging I was able to find out that `APushService` is empty when running on `iOS`, but not on `Android`.

```
procedure TFormLogin.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
    APushService           : TPushService;
begin

    APushService       := TPushServiceManager.Instance.GetServiceByName(TPushService.TServiceNames.APS);

end;
```

Am I doing something wrong? How can we enable Push Notifications for iOS on Delphi?

Any ideas would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What could possibly make `GetServiceByName` not find the service?

Comment: I have no idea. I don't have the source code, but you do. Try looking in *System.PushNotification.pas* for clues. Maybe the service with that name doesn't exist. Maybe your app doesn't have sufficient permission to see the result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution was comically simple for the amount of effort we took to solve.

`FMX.PushNotification.iOS` import was missing in the code.

Funny thing is: if we remove the `PushNotifications` imports, `Delphi Seattle` won't show any warnings.

Answer (score 0):

Here is working code that I use for Android and iOS:

```
const
  FAndroidServerKey = '63538920422';

private
  { Private declarations }
  FDeviceID: string;
  FDeviceToken: string;

  FPushService: TPushService;
  FPushServiceConnection: TPushServiceConnection;

  procedure OnReceiveNotificationEvent(Sender: TObject; 
    const ANotification: TPushServiceNotification);
  procedure OnServiceConnectionChange(Sender: TObject; 
    AChange: TPushService.TChanges);

  procedure PushServiceRegister;

procedure TFormMain.OnReceiveNotificationEvent(Sender: TObject; 
  const ANotification: TPushServiceNotification);
const
  FCMSignature = 'gcm.notification.body';
  GCMSignature = 'message';
  APNsSignature = 'alert';
var
  aText: string;
  aObj: TJSONValue;
begin
  // this will fire when only when app is opened
{$IFDEF ANDROID}
  aObj := ANotification.DataObject.GetValue(GCMSignature);
  if aObj <> nil then
    aText := aObj.Value
  else
    aText := ANotification.DataObject.GetValue(FCMSignature).Value;
{$ELSE}
  aObj := ANotification.DataObject.GetValue(APNsSignature);
  if aObj <> nil then
    aText := aObj.Value;
{$ENDIF}
  ShowMessage(aText);
end;

procedure TFormMain.OnServiceConnectionChange(Sender: TObject; 
  AChange: TPushService.TChanges);
begin
  if (TPushService.TChange.DeviceToken in AChange) and
    Assigned(FPushServiceConnection) then
  begin
    FDeviceID := FPushService.DeviceIDValue[TPushService.TDeviceIDNames.DeviceID];
    FDeviceToken := FPushService.DeviceTokenValue
      [TPushService.TDeviceTokenNames.DeviceToken];
    // save token and ID to  remote db here
  end;
end;

procedure TFormMain.PushServiceRegister;
begin
  FPushService := nil;
  FPushServiceConnection := nil;

{$IF defined(ANDROID)}
  FPushService := TPushServiceManager.Instance.GetServiceByName<
    (TPushService.TServiceNames.GCM);
  FPushService.AppProps[TPushService.TAppPropNames.GCMAppID] := FAndroidServerKey;
{$ENDIF}
{$IF defined(IOS) AND defined(CPUARM)}
  FPushService := TPushServiceManager.Instance.GetServiceByName
   (TPushService.TServiceNames.APS);
{$ENDIF}
  if Assigned(FPushService) then
  begin
    FPushServiceConnection := TPushServiceConnection.Create(FPushService);
    FPushServiceConnection.OnChange := OnServiceConnectionChange;
    FPushServiceConnection.OnReceiveNotification := OnReceiveNotificationEvent;
    FPushServiceConnection.Active := true; // this will fires OnChange event
  end;
end;
```

Here is details step by step article for android and iOS (use google translate) for C++ and Delphi code with ready to use PHP server code.

http://blog.rzaripov.kz/2017/02/firebase-android-ios.html
http://blog.rzaripov.kz/2017/02/firebase-android-ios-2.html

Use this forum to ask questions (you may use English)
[http://fire-monkey.ru/topic/1809-статья-php-сервер-для-рассылки-push-на-android-и-ios/](http://fire-monkey.ru/topic/1809-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%8F-php-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B8-push-%D0%BD%D0%B0-android-%D0%B8-ios/)